# iOS : Core Text - loosing context when drawing image inside a block

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing, cgcontext, core-text

I'm currently working on a FTCoreText module edit to load images directly from the web and display them with Core Text.
So, i have made some edits to https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTCoreText/blob/master/FTCoreText/classes/FTCoreTextView.m#L1149 to use the UIImageView category of AFNetworking. Now, I use a block which will download the image from internet and draw it to the view. The image is drawn, but I have errors with the context :

```
Aug 13 05:34:50 Yohann-iPhone CCFA[9878] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 05:34:50 Yohann-iPhone CCFA[9878] <Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 05:34:50 Yohann-iPhone CCFA[9878] <Error>: CGContextSetBlendMode: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 05:34:50 Yohann-iPhone CCFA[9878] <Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 05:34:50 Yohann-iPhone CCFA[9878] <Error>: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 05:34:50 Yohann-iPhone CCFA[9878] <Error>: CGContextScaleCTM: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 05:34:50 Yohann-iPhone CCFA[9878] <Error>: CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0
Aug 13 05:34:50 Yohann-iPhone CCFA[9878] <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

You can see my block here :

```
UIImageView *imgNode = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageNode.imageName]];
[imgNode setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rien.gif"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                if (alignment == kCTRightTextAlignment) x = (self.frame.size.width - image.size.width);
                if (alignment == kCTCenterTextAlignment) x = ((self.frame.size.width - image.size.width) / 2);

                frame = CGRectMake(x, (lineFrame.origin.y - image.size.height), image.size.width, image.size.height);


                if (alignment != kCTCenterTextAlignment) frame.origin.x = (alignment == kCTLeftTextAlignment)? insets.left : (self.frame.size.width - image.size.width - insets.right);
                frame.origin.y += insets.top;
                frame.size.width = ((insets.left + insets.right + image.size.width ) > self.frame.size.width)? self.frame.size.width : image.size.width;


                frame = CGRectMake((((320-2*20)-image.size.width)/2), frame.origin.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
                NSLog(@"Frame : %f %f", frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
                NSLog(@"Image : %f %f", image.size.width, image.size.height);
                CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();                       
                CGContextSaveGState(context);

                [image drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(frame)];
            } failure:nil];
            [imgNode.image drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(frame)];
```

And of course, i pastebin you the entire code : http://pastebin.com/Qj6PtEFj

I hope you can help me :) !

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and solved it with `UIGraphicsPushContext(context)/UIGraphicsPushContext(context)` around the drawing code. context was created with

```
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 0, space, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just suggestion, if the you meet the error like

> “CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0“

means you are not working on the correct context, that `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` is not correct. Get the original context where the draw happens and pass it to the complete block.